# NSTimer causes "unrecognized selector" crash when it fires

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector, nstimer

I'm using a `NSTimer` to run an animation (for now just call it `myMethod`). However, its causing a crash.

Here's the code:

```
@implementation SecondViewController


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


- (void) myMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Mark Timer Fire");

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];



NSLog(@"We've loaded scan");

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(myMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];


}
```

And here's the output during the crash

> -[SecondViewController myMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b2ca40
>   2012-06-21 12:19:53.297 Lie Detector[38912:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SecondViewController myMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b2ca40'

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either you can use only

```
- (void)myMethod: (id)sender
{
 // Do things
}
```

or you can do (remove : from both the method name)..

```
animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

hope this will help you

Comment: The first option is the correct one except that the parameter should really be typed as `(NSTimer *)`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem while using Swift. It may not be evident that in Swift I discovered that the target object of NSTimer must be an NSObject.

```
class Timer : NSObject {
   init () { super.init() }
   func schedule() {
      NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0,
                             target: self,
                             selector: "myMethod",
                             userInfo: nil,
                            repeats: true)
  }
  func myMethod() {
     ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

replace this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(myMethod:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];
```

by this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(myMethod)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];
```

Comment: This is a good answer, I don't understand why they are downvoting this. +1 for compensation.

Answer (score 2):

The timer's action method [should take one argument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW1):

```
- (void)myMethod: (NSTimer *)tim
{
     // Do things
}
```

The name of this method is `myMethod:`, including the colon. Your current method's name is `myMethod`, *without* the colon, but you create your timer by passing a method name that has it: `selector:@selector(myMethod:)`.

Currently, then, the timer sends the message `myMethod:` to your object; your object doesn't respond to that (but would respond to `myMethod`) and raises an exception.